# reference a multi dimensional array with strings not numbers

Tags: javascript

I have the following bit if java script, I want to reference multi dimensional arrays using names rather than numbers, I thought the following code would work :

```
  var detail=new Array()

  detail['Big Trailer']=new Array()

  detail['Big Trailer']['Bill'] = 'driving to London' 

  detail['Big Trailer']['John'] = 'driving to Scotland'
```

But when I try and reference the array I get undefined for all my attempts

```
  Alert ( detail['Big Trailer]['john'] )
```

Do I have to reference these arrays using numbers like detail[1,0] , I can I do this with strings ? any help please ?

Comment: You are writing to `['John']`, but reading from `['john']`. Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Did you really try it? Because that *would* have worked, except for the case-senstivity and syntax issues on the "Alert" line. Okay, maybe a "vanilla object" is more suitable for a Map, but an Array works like any other object (with a few special properties).

Comment: Thanks , I amended the code its all good, Prior to the typo I was sure  it was not working, But all is well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want an object, not an array:

```
var detail = {};
detail['Big Trailer'] = {};
detail['Big Trailer']['Bill'] = 'driving to London';
detail['Big Trailer']['John'] = 'driving to Scotland';

alert(detail['Big Trailer']['John']); // driving to Scotland
```

Answer (score 4):

For one thing, arrays are purely numeric indexes. However since an array is a kind of Object, you can assign properties to it by string.

However, the problem with your example above (assuming the missing `'` is a typo) is that the keys are case-sensetive. If you type `'John'` in one place, you MUST type `'John'` in others.

Comment: Agreed. `John` and `john` are entirely different properties of the same object.